# From LyX to LaTeX and back without losing information

Tags: lyx, import, export

I work in LyX but my colleagues work in LaTeX. If I export from LyX to LaTeX, then send them the tex file, then receive the tex file with their editions and then import it back to LyX, will I have all my information there? I.e., suppose their edit involves only the text, will my new LyX file will indeed be identical to the previous LyX file with only the text changes?

I ask because with other software (such as Word), information might be lost during export and import.

Comment: In general, whenever you export/import anything, information will be lost (there are of course examples, but LyX is not one). For example, if you convert a .jpg to .gif and then back to .jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LyX is pretty reasonable at exporting to LaTeX, although it could usually do with a bit of tweaking (a good start is removing the "do not edit this file" comment from the start of the exported file). But it is notoriously bad at importing TeX files. Expect very poor results at that, I'm afraid.